# PHP warnings after reindex

Tags: magento-2.1, php, reindex

im new to the Magento webshop thing. i manage with UNIX, but im not particularly skilled.
still, i managed to get my second magentshop runing, this one on a VPS on which i installed evrything myself without any help (pretty proud about that)

now i have some strange behaviour inside my PHP which i cant google and im not qualified to understand it properly

does somebody know whats going and/or how to correct this?
if not, is this a problem? will it slow down the shop?

magento is 2.1.7, custom (payed) theme, PHP7.0, MySQL server 5.6 and Apache 2.4

error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0    

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_intl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_intl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0    

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0    

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_exif.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_exif.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0    

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_xsl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_xsl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0    

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Event\mb_strtolower() in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:56
```

Stack trace:

```
0 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('model_load_befo...', Array)    

1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(562): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('model_load_befo...', Array)    

2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(530): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->_beforeLoad('1', NULL)    

3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php(488): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->load('1', NULL)    

4 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/Store/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Store\Model\Store->load('1', NULL)    

5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(181): Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor->load('1')    

6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/A in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php on line 56
```

anyone who can shed light on this is welcome - thanks

steve

PS im no professional developer, i just need those webshops to run for my business ;)